# Setting exception handled in Web API ExceptionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Is there any way in ASP.NET Web API to mark an exception as handled in an ExceptionFilterAttribute?

I want to handle the exception at the method level with an exception filter and stop the propagation to a globally registered exception filter.

Filter used on a controller action:

```
public class MethodExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is NotImplementedException)
        {
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(context.Exception.Message)
            };
            // here in MVC you could set context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The globally registered filter:

```
public class GlobalExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is SomeOtherException)
        {
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.SomethingElse)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(context.Exception.Message)
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you, please, put a sample of your "handle the exception at the method level with an exception filter"?

Comment: In order to get to the global filter the exception has to be unhandled in the method in the first place I think - so why not wrap the unsafe code in a `try/catch` block and handle it there?

Answer (score 2):

Try throwing an [HttpResponseException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpresponseexception.aspx) at the end of your local handling. By design, they are not caught by exception filters.

```
throw new HttpResponseException(context.Response);
```

Comment: Old answer, but I just wanted to point out it doesn't prevent more handling to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Web API 2 is designed with [inversion of control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection) in mind. You consider the possibility for the exception to already be handled, rather than interrupting the filter execution after you handle it.

In this sense, attributes deriving from `ExceptionFilterAttribute` should check if the exception is already handled, which your code already does since `is` operator returns false for `null` values. In addition, after you handle the exception, you set `context.Exception` to `null` in order to avoid further handling.

To achieve this in your code, you need to replace your comment from `MethodExceptionFilterAttribute` with `context.Exception = null` to clear the exception.

It is important to note that it is not a good idea to register more than one global exception filter, due to ordering issues. For information about the execution order of attribute filters in Web API, see the following thread [Order of execution with multiple filters in web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628467/order-of-execution-with-multiple-filters-in-web-api).