# Order of execution with multiple filters in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, action-filter, asp.net-web-api2

I am using latest `web api`.

I do annotate *some* controllers with 3 different filter attributes.

```
1 [Authorize]
2 [RessourceOwnerAttribute derived from AuthorizationFilterAttribute]
3 [InvalidModelStateAttribute derived from ActionFilterAttribute]
```

I can not be sure that the filters run in the order they are declared from top to down.

How do I define the order of execution in `web api 2.1` ?

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1065#

http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/147201-asp-net-web-api/suggestions/3346720-execution-order-of-mvc4-webapi-action-filters

Do I still have to fix that for myself ??

Comment: Does this link: https://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/control-the-execution-order-of-your-filters-in-asp-net-web-api/ help?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Some things to note here:

1. Filters get executed in the following order for an action: Globally
   Defined Filters -> Controller-specific Filters -> Action-specific Filters.
2. Authorization Filters -> Action Filters -> Exception
   Filters
3. Now the problem that you seem to mention is related to
   having *multiple* filters of the same kind (ex: Multiple
   `ActionFilterAttribute` decorated on a
   controller or an action. This is the case which would not guarantee
   the order as its based on reflection.). For this case, there is a way 
   to do it in Web API using    custom implementation of 
   `System.Web.Http.Filters.IFilterProvider`. I have tried the following 
   and did some testing to verify it. It seems to work fine. 
   You can give it a try and see if it works as you expected.

   ```
   // Start clean by replacing with filter provider for global configuration.
   // For these globally added filters we need not do any ordering as filters are 
   // executed in the order they are added to the filter collection
   config.Services.Replace(typeof(IFilterProvider), new System.Web.Http.Filters.ConfigurationFilterProvider());

   // Custom action filter provider which does ordering
   config.Services.Add(typeof(IFilterProvider), new OrderedFilterProvider());
   ```

   ---

   ```
   public class OrderedFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
   {
       public IEnumerable<FilterInfo> GetFilters(HttpConfiguration configuration, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
       {
           // controller-specific
           IEnumerable<FilterInfo> controllerSpecificFilters = OrderFilters(actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetFilters(), FilterScope.Controller);

           // action-specific
           IEnumerable<FilterInfo> actionSpecificFilters = OrderFilters(actionDescriptor.GetFilters(), FilterScope.Action);

           return controllerSpecificFilters.Concat(actionSpecificFilters);
       }

       private IEnumerable<FilterInfo> OrderFilters(IEnumerable<IFilter> filters, FilterScope scope)
       {
           return filters.OfType<IOrderedFilter>()
                           .OrderBy(filter => filter.Order)
                           .Select(instance => new FilterInfo(instance, scope));
       }
   }
   ```

   ---

   ```
   //NOTE: Here I am creating base attributes which you would need to inherit from.
   public interface IOrderedFilter : IFilter
   {
       int Order { get; set; }
   }

   public class ActionFilterWithOrderAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IOrderedFilter
   {
       public int Order { get; set; }
   }

   public class AuthorizationFilterWithOrderAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute, IOrderedFilter
   {
       public int Order { get; set; }
   }

   public class ExceptionFilterWithOrderAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute, IOrderedFilter
   {
       public int Order { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Comment: Which file to add the `config.Services.Replace(...` Code?

Comment: @KiranChalla What about globally defined action filters?

Comment: Its executing the globally defined filter no matter what the collection is ordered. Anyway around this?

Comment: And once again, where does the config.Services.Replace(... code go?

Comment: @freakinthesun: The call to `config.Services.Replace` goes in your `Startup` if you're hosting with the OWIN pipeline, or in Global.asax.cs if you're not.

Comment: I had another answer providing some improvements. Feel free to have a look.

Comment: @MIKE I'm having the same problem - it's caused by the call to `config.Services.Replace`, but I don't have a solution right now.

Comment: For reference, order of filters at: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_mvc/asp.net_mvc_filters.htm

Comment: @Abacus that reference is for MVC filters. The ordering being discussed is for Web API filters. MVC filters have the ability to specify ordering built-in.

Answer (score 24):

I had some problems with the solution from Kiran Challa 's answer.
Here is my modification.

The problem was in the method

```
private IEnumerable<FilterInfo> OrderFilters(IEnumerable<IFilter> filters, FilterScope scope)
{
    return filters.OfType<IOrderedFilter>()
                    .OrderBy(filter => filter.Order)
                    .Select(instance => new FilterInfo(instance, scope));
}
```

As you can see **only** filters that implement `IOrderedFilter` will get returned. I had a third party attribute that gets cut of and as a result not executed.

So i had two possible solutions.

1. Use inheritance to create a extended version of the third party attribute in order to make it implement `IOrderFilter` too.
2. Change the method to treat every attribute wich does not implement `IOrderFilter` like a `IOrderFilter` attribute with the order number of 0 and combine it with the `IOrderFilter` attributes, order and return them.

The second solution is better cause it allows me to bring my `IOrderFilter` attribute before third party attributes that does not implement `IOrderFilter`.

### Sample

```
[NonOrderableThirdPartyAttribute]
[OrderableAttributeA(Order = -1)]
[OrderableAttributeB(Order = 1)]
[OrderableAttributeC(Order = 2)]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(... request) 
{
    // do something
}
```

So the execution would be

- OrderableAttributeA
- NonOrderableThirdPartyAttribute
- OrderableAttributeB
- OrderableAttributeC

### So here is the modified code

```
public class OrderedFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<FilterInfo> GetFilters(HttpConfiguration configuration, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        // controller-specific
        var controllerSpecificFilters = OrderFilters(actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetFilters(), FilterScope.Controller);

        // action-specific
        var actionSpecificFilters = OrderFilters(actionDescriptor.GetFilters(), FilterScope.Action);

        return controllerSpecificFilters.Concat(actionSpecificFilters);
    }

    private IEnumerable<FilterInfo> OrderFilters(IEnumerable<IFilter> filters, FilterScope scope)
    {
        // get all filter that dont implement IOrderedFilter and give them order number of 0
        var notOrderableFilter = filters.Where(f => !(f is IOrderedFilter))
            .Select(instance => new KeyValuePair<int, FilterInfo>(0, new FilterInfo(instance, scope)));

        // get all filter that implement IOrderFilter and give them order number from the instance
        var orderableFilter = filters.OfType<IOrderedFilter>().OrderBy(filter => filter.Order)
            .Select(instance => new KeyValuePair<int, FilterInfo>(instance.Order, new FilterInfo(instance, scope)));

        // concat lists => order => return
        return notOrderableFilter.Concat(orderableFilter).OrderBy(x => x.Key).Select(y => y.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In asp.net core you can manage that using [IOrderedFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iorderedfilter?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

```
public class MyFilter : IActionFilter, IOrderedFilter
{
    public int Order => 1; // define the order here
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple filters of the same kind, the execution order will be 
Global -> Controller -> Action

And for authorization filter, if you set multiple filters at different levels, they will be combined with an "AND" and will be calculated in the above execution order.

And the authorization process will fail at the first failed filter.

For more details, you can check this post.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 0):

If multiple filters are implemented in MVC then the order of executing will be

1. Authorization filter
2. Action filter
3. Result filter
4. Exception filter