# ASP.NET Web API Exception Filter isn't invoked when Action Filter creates response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Using Web API, I have an exception filter that is supposed to write a custom payload using data from certain exceptions. This works fine.

However, I'm also using an action filter that is supposed to add some HTTP headers to the response message. This works fine when no exception is thrown.

When an exception is thrown, though, my action filter is given a NULL Response (HttpActionExecuted.Response), and can therefore not add its headers. I've attempted to solve this by creating a new ResponseMessage before adding the headers if the response is NULL. But when I create a new ResponseMessage in the action filter, my exception filter is no longer invoked.

I guess the Web API model somehow figures no exception was thrown if a response message exists. Any ideas to how I can use an exception filter, while still having an action filter adding HTTP headers?

My exception filter:

```cs
public class ExceptionStatusFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (!(context.Exception is CertainException))
        {
            return;
        }

        var exception = context.Exception as CertainException;

        var error = new DefaultErrorContainer
        {
            Error = new Error
            {
                Description = exception.Message,
                ErrorCode = exception.ErrorCode,
                ErrorThirdParty = exception.ThirdPartyErrorCode
            }
        };

        context.Response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, error);
    }
}
```

And the action filter:

```cs
public class ProfilingActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var header = "foo";

        if (context.Response == null)
        {
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        }

        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-SOME-HEADER", header);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you applying filters to actions? I mean share your controller action as well.

Comment: Both filters are applied to the actions by decorating the controller as attributes.

Answer (score 0):

From this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628467/order-of-execution-with-multiple-filters-in-web-api) you can get to know the order in which Action filters are getting called.

Exception filters are last ones to get called, so if you are generating a response or handling the exception before this filter gets executes, your Exception filter will assume no exception is thrown and it wont execute.

My suggestion would be on exception, create a response and attach header separately to this exception response as well.

This [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling) can also help.

```
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            if (context.Exception is NotImplementedException)
            {
                context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
                // Append Header here.
                context.Response.Headers.Add("X-SOME-HEADER", header);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm well aware that exception filters are the last ones to get called. What puzzles me is why they don't get called when context.Response != null. Is there a way of telling the pipeline that the thrown exception hasn't been handled, like in MVC?

Comment: Attaching the necessary headers in the exception filter feels like a severe violation of Seperation of Concerns.

Comment: I've tried having the action filter re-throw the exception after setting its headers. This ensures the exception filter is invoked, but the response is erased, removing the headers before it reached the exception filter. It's starting to look like I might have to store the extra headers in e.g. Request.Items and have a message handler that adds them to the response. Makes for a brittle design, though.