# Multiple ActionFilterAttribute order of execution assured?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

I just looked into ActionFilters and they are quite useful. Now, I tried having more than one decorating a method, so as to separate the logic. I thought this would be useful.

So here's an example method

```
[Common.PortalSecurity.Login]
[Common.PortalSecurity.UserRole]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAll(string sessionToken)
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage();
}
```

This works fine, but it is mandatory that `Login` should execute before `UserRole`.

Is it 100% the order of execution will be respected at every request ?

This [blog post](http://byatool.com/lessons/asp-net-mvc-attributes-actionfilterattribute-and-why-you-might-want-to-use-them/) seems to say it should work.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Following is an example of how you could do this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628467/order-of-execution-with-multiple-filters-in-web-api

Comment: @KiranChalla Thanks. Could you show an example of how you would decorate a controller method with that solution ?

Comment: @KiranChalla Nevermind, had it working :) Edited my answer.

Comment: You should use Authentication or Authorization filters for login security, these execute before action filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the solution proposed above working as such:

Your custom attributes have to inherit:

```
public class LoginAttribute : ActionFilterWithOrderAttribute
{

}

public class UserRoleAttribute : ActionFilterWithOrderAttribute
{

}
```

And a method wanting to use it should be decorated as:

```
[Common.PortalSecurity.Login(Order=1)]
[Common.PortalSecurity.UserRole(Order=2)]  
public HttpResponseMessage GetAll(string sessionToken)
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage();
}
```

Comment: Has this been changed?  I can only declare an `ActionFilterAttribute` and not `ActionFilterWithOrderAttribute` though I can use `Order=1`.

Comment: Yes, my solution works using this. What is your problem exactly ?

Comment: Visual studio 2013 just doesn't allow an `ActionFilterWithOrderAttribute` for me (though maybe I'm doing something wrong).  It appears to be applying the orders correctly with just `ActionFilterAttribute` so your solution here saved me!

Comment: @Aarmora Well, I'm using VS2010 and .NET/MVC 4, so it might be different if you are using different versions. I think MVC5 has proper ordering without that fix.

Comment: I've found the implementation of ActionFilterWithOrderAttribute described in this answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628467/order-of-execution-with-multiple-filters-in-web-api

Answer (score 0):

In **MVC5** you inherit from **ActionFilter** and indicate the order (**using Order** property of ActionFilter) in the custom attribute like this:

```
[Common.PortalSecurity.Login(Order=1)]
[Common.PortalSecurity.UserRole(Order=2)]  
public HttpResponseMessage GetAll(string sessionToken)
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage();
}
```

You can get more information at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterattribute.order(v=vs.118).aspx