# Are global ASP.NET Web API filters always executed in order?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I add a number of global ASP.NET Web API filters (where `config` is my `System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration`:

```
config.Filters.Add(new SomeFilter());
config.Filters.Add(new AnotherFilter());
config.Filters.Add(new YetAnotherField());
```

Are these filters always executed in the above order?
I have never experienced them not executing in order while testing but want to make sure cause I have noticed some exceptions in our logs that might happen if they are not in order (might be another cause as well though).

The `HttpFilterCollection` documentation doesn't specifically state it retains order (though the `Add` method documentation does state that it adds an item to the end of the collection)

Comment: This looks like a dupe, but I don't feel confident enough to dupehammer... take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628467/order-of-execution-with-multiple-filters-in-web-api

Comment: [This](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/control-the-execution-order-of-your-filters-in-asp-net-web-api/) may also help.

Comment: I do believe both those links are specific to filters applied by attribute which uses reflection and thus order is not guaranteed. In my case it is manually adding it directly to the `HttpFilterCollection`

Answer (score 3):

Based on WebApi and Linq sources, filters execution order is:

1. AuthenticationFilters
2. AuthorizationFilters
3. ActionFilters, based on scope

   - Global
   - Controller
   - Action
4. ExceptionFilters

Filters of same type and scope will be executed in the same order they was added to FilterCollection.

Example:

```
config.Filters.Add(new ActionFilterAttribute1());
config.Filters.Add(new AuthenticationFilter());
config.Filters.Add(new ActionFilterAttribute2());
```

Execution order will be

1. AuthenticationFilter
2. ActionFilterAttribute1
3. ActionFilterAttribute2

Comment: Note that the above order seems to be correct for the OnActionExecutING. But for the OnActionExecutED it looks like the order is reversed.