# asp.net web api 2.2 AuthorizationFilterAttribute manage order

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using **asp.net web api 2.2**. I have created 3 AuthorizationFilterAttribute. Lets call them `A, B & C`. Since these filters are global filters I have added them under `WebApiConfig.cs` file.

```
config.Filters.Add(new A());
config.Filters.Add(new B());
config.Filters.Add(new C());
```

All the filters are AuthorizationFilter & are global (not specific to controller or action). I want to ensure Filter A get executed first then filter B and then filter C.

What do I need to do to ensure filters gets executed in specific order? `So far What I am seeing is, the filters get called in the order in which they got added.`

Comment: Could you aggregate your filter logic in to one filter? You would have total control over the execution order then.

Comment: @James: I will do that only if I do not come across any solid answer. Currently the filters are getting executed in same order in which they got added. But I have not come across any article that confirm the same.

Comment: It doesn't seem like much has changed here since 2.1, so this should apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628467/order-of-execution-with-multiple-filters-in-web-api