# WEB API: How to control the execution order of action filters which is implemented by IAutofacActionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have multiple action filters which is implemented from IAutofacActionFilter. I want to control the order of execution. So that my Logging action filter will execute first before other action filter. Please.

I want to implement this globally. I dont want to specify any attribute on each method of controller as I have 100 controllers with 10000 contoller methods.

Comment: could you please share me a exact existing Q & A web link please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628467/order-of-execution-with-multiple-filters-in-web-api

Comment: This is talks about order of different type of filters. But my question is to order only action filters.. not auth or exception filters...

Comment: I gave to the reason on how this is different from existing questions. could u please remove the Duplicate flag ..

Comment: Filters of the same type are executed in the order they are registered

Comment: ok. If I register actionFilterA first and actionFilterB 2nd, then actionFilterB executes first but the cycle end at actionFilterA. So I am not able to depend on registration. Because I need to start and stop the logging at same action filter.