# Is it possible to change the order of execution of action filter attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

We have a Web API project with a few different implementations of `ActionFilterAttribute`. One is added globally to all actions as part of the application startup

`filters.Add(new ContractValidationAttribute());`

Others are used to decorate specific action methods.

The global filter is always executed first, but I need it to be executed last, or at least after all other implementations of `ActionFilterAttribute`. Is this possible?

I understand that by default filters are executed as groups in the following order: Globally Defined Filters -> Controller-specific Filters -> Action-specific Filters. It is possible to affect the order of execution within one of these groups (e.g. [Order of execution with multiple filters in web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628467/order-of-execution-with-multiple-filters-in-web-api)) but not to move, as I want, the execution of an action-specific filter before a global one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order of execution with multiple filters in web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628467/order-of-execution-with-multiple-filters-in-web-api)

Comment: @dan-wilson No, not a duplicate. I've updated the question to make it clear why.

Comment: Kiran Challa's solution using a common `Order` property on your attributes and `IFilterProvider` should cover your use case. Does it not?

Comment: No, the ordering was only applied within the contextual group, so global filters run in order, then controller filters run in order etc.

Comment: Oh, then I don't think what you'd like to achieve is possible without forking the framework itself. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) makes no mention of changing when global filters execute.